# How to make Django Compressor work with LessCSS on Windows

Tags: django, less, django-compressor

I'd like to know how I can make Django Compressor work with LessCSS on Windows.

lessc is installed

```
C:\>lessc
    dotless Compiler 1.1.0.7
    Compiles .less files to css files.
```

Django Pipeline Settings

> COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
>       ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'), )

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),
)
```

And this in your template:

```
{% load compress %}

{% compress css %}
<link type="text/less" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.less" charset="utf-8">
{% endcompress %}
```

Comment: `rel="stylesheet"` made the difference, as opposed to `rel="stylesheet/less"`, which was recommended on the [less homepage] (http://lesscss.org)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the ruby version of less (and not the nodejs version), then you should use:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', 'lessc {infile}'),
)
```

and not

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/less', 'lessc {infile} {outfile}'),
)
```